# Speech to Text On Google Cloud printing nothing. Short Audio File that is local (30s)

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I want to transcribe a local short audio file into text using Google speech to text. I have downloaded their JSON code for doing this with a short audio file and it appears to be connecting to the API and printing nothing.

I have tried converting the audio files into .wav, .mp3, .flac. 
I also commenting out all or some the RecognitionConfig parameters, changing the encoding Parameter, 
changing the sample_rate_hertz form 16000 to 44100, 
and adding audio_channel_count = 1

I Used Sox to look at the exact formatting of the file

Here is the short speech to text code I got from google: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize

```
with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    audio_channel_count=1,
    language_code='en-US')

response = client.recognize(config, audio)

print(response)
# Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
# them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
for result in response.results:
    # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
    print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

I would expect to see a transrcipt that looks something this:

*investi-gation, you know, the Democratic break-in
thing, we're back to the-in the, the problem
area because the FBI is not under control,
because Gray doesn't exactly know how to
control them, and they have, their
investigation is now leading into some
productive areas, because they've been able
to trace the money, not through the money
itself, but through the bank,*

Comment: share the file you are trying